# Intel IPP convolution deprecated -- is there a different IPP 2D convolution method?

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, intel-ipp

I'm experimenting with  [Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (IPP)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp/), and I'm curious about the "right way" to do 2D convolution in IPP.

According to the Intel IPP documentation, `ippiConvFull` ([documentation](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/ipp_sa/71/ipp_manual/IPPI/ippi_ch9/functn_ConvFull.htm)) and `ippiConvValid` ([documentation](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/ipp_sa/71/ipp_manual/IPPI/ippi_ch9/functn_ConvValid.htm)) are deprecated. However I don't see any other 2D convolution routines in IPP.

I did some searching, and I didn't find any alternative IPP functions for 2D image convolution.

- Is there a replacement for `ippiConvFull` and `ippiConvValid` in IPP?
- Or, is Intel just removing convolution from IPP?

Comment: hey @solving, Isn't a 2D Convolution just a repetition of a 1D convolution in either dimension?

Comment: @AK4749 Only for separable kernels, like Gaussian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ippiFilter](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/ipp_sa/71/ipp_manual/IPPI/ippi_ch9/functn_Filter.htm) instead. It is not marked as deprecated and operates in 2D.

Comment: Ah, nice. I didn't realize that there was a plain `ippiFilter` that didn't have a built-in kernel (e.g. `ippiFilterBox` for smoothing). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems they are deprecated (At least not in the latest IPP v 8.1):

[Intel IPP Convolution](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/504168).

Yet, there's a new function [`ippiConv`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/504170) which does both using the flag `algType`.

It should work for you.